# Как зажать пкм использую любую библиотеку

Tags: python

Используя любую библиотеку пайтон нужна зажать пкм

Comment: Что вы пробовали? Что у вас получилось?

Answer (score 2):

## Поднять мышку

Для этого воспользуйтесь библиотекой `pyautogui`. Исходя из [документации](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html#the-mousedown-and-mouseup-functions), вы можете использовать функцию `mouseDown`:

```py
import pyautogui # Импортировать библиотеку
pyautogui.mouseDown(button = 'right') # Держать правую клавишу мышки
```

Текст из документации:

> Mouse clicks and drags are composed of both pressing the mouse button
> down and releasing it back up. If you want to perform these actions
> separately, call the mouseDown() and mouseUp() functions. They have
> the same x, y, and button. For example:
>
> ```py
> pyautogui.mouseDown(button='right')  # press the right button down
> pyautogui.mouseUp(button='right', x=100, y=200) # move the mouse to 100, 200, then release the right button up.
> pyautogui.mouseDown(); pyautogui.mouseUp() # does the same thing as a left-button mouse click
> ```

## Отпустить мышку

Чтобы отпустить мышку, используйте функцию `mouseUp`:

```py
pyautogui.mouseUp()
```

## Установка библиотеки

Для установки библиотеки:

1. Откройте терминал
2. Введите команду:
   2.1. Если у вас Windows, напишите `py -m pip install pyautogui`.
   2.2. Если у вас Linux, напишите `python -m pip install pyautogui`.
3. Нажмите Enter и радуйтесь.

Comment: это держать, а мне надо чтоб зажало

Comment: Вы имеете в виду просто кликнуть ПКМ?

Comment: вот нажми на пкм и не отпускай, вот это мне надо

Comment: Возьмите код под заголовком "Поднять мышку". И не вставляйте код под заголовком "Отпустить мышку". Вот и всё.

Comment: точнее он берёт и всё, а мне надо чтоб именно зажимало

Comment: он не зажимает,

Comment: Вы установили библиотеку? Вот сам код: `import pyautogui; pyautogui.mouseDown(button = 'right')`

Comment: он не так работает как надо

Comment: А как он должен работать? У вас получилось установить библиотеку? Если да, то он должен работать. Может быть я в чём-то ошибаюсь?

Comment: @Max, может вам стоит сперва немного подтянуть основы программирования, а уже потом лезть в библиотеки и пробовать делать то, что на данном этапе вы не в силах понять?